# how to pass data to server without using form submit in laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a new user of laravel. I have problem in pass data to server in laravel 4.2. I didn't use a form submit, I use javascript to refer action of form such the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".delete_action").click(function(event){
        $("#deletecategory").prop('href','/admin/category/'+ event.target.id +'/delete');
    });
});
```

and my modal of delete like this:

×
              
             

            
              ​​​​​​​ Are you sure want to delete this category?
            

            
              Yes
              No

When i click Yes, it doesn't do anything. I hope to get some solution from you!

Comment: Did try using ajax for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for this.

```
$('#yourOkButton').click(function(){$.ajax(...);});
```

In the documentation of $.ajax is everything written down.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include an ajax call... to actually submit data...

Like so...

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $(".delete_action").click(function(event){
        // incase the button is inside a form, this will prevent it from submitting
        event.preventDefault();
        // get your url
        var url = '/admin/category/'+ event.target.id +'/delete';
        // Create alert to confirm deletion
        var conf = confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete this?");
        if(conf){
        // If they click yes
        // submit via ajax
          $.ajax({
            url:url,
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data){
             //put anything you want to do here after success
             // Probably remove the element from the page since you deleted it               //So if the button is part of a parent div that needs to be removed.
            }
         });
       }
    });
  });
```

You could also use $.get instead of $.ajax to shorten the code some more...

```
   $.get(url, function(data){
      //remove element after success
   });
```

But I realize youre trying to pass the url to a modal window, and then submitting that modal window.  So you need to attach the ajax call to the modal window button.  Not like above, which is just opening an alert window.  Its the easier way, but less fancy looking.  If you really want a modal.  You need to attach the above code to the modal confirm button.  But the gist is the same.